# Could not load .js files into Angular 4 application

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am trying to use a pre designed bootstrap template in my Angular 4 application (template - https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/).  The css styles loaded successfully. But when loading the required .js files, it gives the following warning. Also the effects that should be provided by the .js files are not working. **How should I properly load these styles and .js files?**

> In angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
    "assets/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js",
    "assets/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js",
    "assets/js/contact_me.js",
    "assets/js/agency.min.js",
    "assets/js/agency.js"
  ],
```

> In styles.css

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
```

> In index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- Custom Style  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

> The warning I get when running ng build

```
WARNING in ./~/raw-loader!./~/source-map-loader!./src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
Cannot find SourceMap 'bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map': Error: Can't resolve './bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map' in 'E:\MEAN 2\MEGATRON\src\assets\vendor\bootstrap\js'
@ ./~/script-loader!./src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js 1:77-292
@ multi script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js script-loader!./src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js script-loader!./src/assets/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.
easing.min.js script-loader!./src/assets/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js script-loader!./src/assets/js/contact_me.js script-loader!./src/assets/js/agency.min.js script-loader!./src/as
sets/js/agency.js
```

Comment: Not related to error, but I think u don't need to add both `assets/js/agency.min.js` and `assets/js/agency.js` as usually they both are same file with just the former a minified version. Only adding `assets/js/agency.min.js` in `angular-cli.json` should work.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` exists in vendor/ directory. I guess you should import it from node_modules/ directory.

```
"scripts": [
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
"../node_modules/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js",
...
]
```

Comment: This eliminated the warning. But bootstrap.bundle.min.js existed in the vendor directory also. I don't know why it created the warning.

Comment: I think sourceMap `bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map` is missing in your vendor/ but exists inside node_modules/